# implementing multiple forms in remix with ZOD

Tags: typescript, remix.run, zod

How can I use zod to handle multiple forms in remix?:
say I want to get some input value named "_intent" and parse the right form data based on the value.

The problem I'm facing is that I get errors because not all forms sends the same formData...

Comment: you are confusing `remix` with `remix.run`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```typescript
export const action = async ({ request }: ActionArgs) => {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const allFormDataFields = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());

  // first extract the intent
  const intent = allFormDataFields._intent as keyof typeof FormIntents;

  if (intent === FormIntents.add_transaction) {
    // now parse with relevant zod object
    const result =
      myZodObject.safeParse(allFormDataFields);
    if (!result.success) {
      return badRequest({
        errorFields: result.error.flatten(),
      });
    }
    // do stuff
  } 
  if(intent === "something else"){
    // do other stuff
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that's the recommended way to handle it.

Comment: thanks! 

BTW, using `safeParse` (with zfd, not zod)  gives me weird type behavior in `useLoaderData<typeof loader>()`. is this related to this? https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/3931

Comment: That's why I wrote `remix-typedjson` which gives me the native return type instead of the one wrapped by `SerializedObject`. Makes everything a lot easier. 

https://github.com/kiliman/remix-typedjson